# gcc - Unable to find Python.framework even though /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework exists?

Tags: python, gcc

I'm running macOS 12.4 here, and I'm trying to compile a sample C program which uses Python's library:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);

    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Py_SetProgramName(program); 
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(\"Hello, world!\")\n");

    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Simply running `gcc ./main.c -o ./main.o` yields the following error:

```
./main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include <Python.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I tried adding "-framework Python" argument so that the final command would look like:

`gcc ./main.c -o ./main.o -framework Python`, but that didn't change anything.

Alternatively, I decided to manually specify the location of the header files:

`gcc ./main.c -o ./main.o -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers`

But now it's complaining about missing symbols (meaning that it can't find the lib).

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyMem_RawFree", referenced from:
      _main in main-e12ebf.o
  "_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags", referenced from:
      _main in main-e12ebf.o
  "_Py_DecodeLocale", referenced from:
      _main in main-e12ebf.o
  "_Py_FinalizeEx", referenced from:
      _main in main-e12ebf.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _main in main-e12ebf.o
  "_Py_SetProgramName", referenced from:
      _main in main-e12ebf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I take my previous command and decide to add `-framework Python` now, it'll just say the framework couldn't be found:

```
ld: framework not found Python
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Same deal with `-lpython`.

I *do* have `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` present on my file system, but for some reason I can't get it to work. I've got Python 3.10.5 and 2.7, both of which were installed using Python's own official DMG installers (and just in case, inside `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`, the `Versions/Current` link points to `Versions/3.10`, so the symlink isn't broken). Beforehand, I tried installing Python 3.9 with homebrew using `brew install python` command, but after the installation, the problem persisted (all of the commands above had the exact same errors).

Additionally, it's not like macOS itself cannot see my Python installations. Both `python` and `python3` commands work in the terminal, and running each one with `--version` argument will print the correct version. `pip` and `pip3` work fine, too.

`Xcode` and `Xcode Command Line Tools` are both installed. As stated before, I'm running macOS 12.4 (Release)

Answer (score 0):

I still couldn't figure this one out, but I did manage to come up with a workaround. I'm still hoping to know what the actual core problem is and how to fix it, though...

In any case, here's what I did:

1. Run this command (add Python lib):

`ln -sf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Python /usr/local/lib/libpython.dylib`

2. Add this line to `~/.bash_profile` (add Python headers):

`export CPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers:{$CPATH}"`

3. Compile with this command:

`gcc ./main.c -o ./main -lpython`